# Magento template for 1.7

Tags: template

i was searching through a template store and they have magento templates for version 1.7 however im using 1.9.2.x. Will the template need to be recoded or just needs to be put into the right directory in verion 1.9.2.x.

Comment: You should use same version.

Answer (score 0):

This depends almost entirely on the quality of the template you are looking to use. Ideally it is much safer to use a template that is already stated as compatible with version 1.9.2 as Adarsh said.

However, there are a number of things you can check if you do really want to use a template for version 1.7:

- Take a look at the quality of the website you are getting the template from. Does it have an active community / lots of people using these templates?
- Do any of the templates have much activity i.e. are any updated frequently?
- Does the template come with any type of support? some marketplaces offer 6 months of free updates / support for premium templates.
- Find the name of the author and Google them! Are they active in forums, are they considered a "credible" Magento developer?
- If you really need to, can you contact the author through the template website or maybe tweet them?

Unless you know exactly what to look for in the quality of code and differences in versions you cannot 100% guarantee you won't run into issues but you can make sure that if you do, you have a way to resolve those issues :)